processing a python yaml file tag with attribue
!Employee old:
    id:   some_id 
    name: John
cfg:
    param: "abc"

I need to load update, and save a yaml file, which contains a structure, similar to the above.
I tried using add_constructor and add_representer. WHich worked when the Tag is placed separately.
!Employee 
old:
    id:   some_id 
    name: John
cfg:
    param: "abc"

I would like nevertheless to avoid the preporcessing of the original file. Also I dont have ruamel (suggested on other posts).
In the example below  yaml does does not seen to scan the entire structure, i.e. does not include the mapping part under the tag.
#====================================================================
import yaml


# Custom class to handle !Employee old: name: Peter
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, status, data=None):
        self.status = status  # e.g., "old"
        self.data = data or {}  # e.g., {'name': 'Peter'}

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"!Employee {self.status}: {self.data}"


# Custom constructor for the !Employee tag
def employee_constructor(loader, node):
    # Check if the node is a MappingNode
    print(f"EMPL_CONST node: {node}")
    if isinstance(node, yaml.MappingNode):
        # Expecting only one key-value pair (e.g., "old": {"name": "Peter"})
        print(f"EMPL_CONST node: {node.value[0]}")
        first_key_node, value_node = node.value[0]

        # The key is the scalar "old"
        status = loader.construct_scalar(first_key_node)

        # The value is the mapping part {"name": "Peter"}
        data = loader.construct_mapping(value_node)

        # Return an Employee object with the status and data
        return Employee(status, data)

    raise yaml.constructor.ConstructorError(None, None, f"Unexpected node type: {type(node)}", node.start_mark)


# Custom representer for the !Employee tag
def employee_representer(dumper, data):
    # Create a tag with the status (e.g., !Employee old)

    tag = f"!Employee"
    return dumper.represent_mapping(tag, {data.status: data.data})

# Register the custom constructor and representer
yaml.add_constructor('!Employee', employee_constructor)
yaml.add_representer(Employee, employee_representer)

def load_yaml(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        # print(data)
    return data
def save_yaml(file_path, data):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(data, file, default_flow_style=False)

# Testing the code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    yaml_string = """
    !Employee old:
        name: Some_Name
        id: some_id
    
    cfg:
        param : 'abc'
    """

    # Load the YAML data`your text`
    data = yaml.load(yaml_string, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    # data = load_yaml("input3.yaml")
    print("Loaded YAML data:")
    print(data)

    # Modify the data (optional)
    data['cfg']['param'] = 'xyz'

    # Dump the data back to YAML format
    output = yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)
    print("\nModified YAML output:")
    print(output)
    save_yaml("output3.yaml", data)


You are using the wrong library to do this kind of round-trip ( load/modify/save ) operations.
With PyYAML you will lose your quotes, comments, apart from having to write a custom loader and dumper.
Additionaly PyYAML can only hanlde a subset of YAML 1.1, which was superseded fifteen years ago.
I recommend you try ruamel.yaml ( diclaiimer: I am the author of that package ):
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
!Employee old:
    [42, 13]:   some_id 
    name: John    # this stays the same
cfg:
    param: "abc"  # this has to change
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['cfg']['param'] = 'xyz'
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

which gives:
!Employee old:
    [42, 13]: some_id
    name: John    # this stays the same
cfg:
    param: "xyz"  # this has to change

